# select where the date is 1 day before/ after a given date. in base SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't really have an example but is there a way in the **basic** SQL to select rows where the date is 1 day before or after a date given by the user?

Comment: no date functions are notorious for being rdbms specific you can try INTERVAL but this is also database specific

Comment: Can you tag the databse used?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the answer will probably depend on which dbms you're using.

Comment: since a few asked, its ms access, 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you specify the parameter in the SQL of the query as a date and then perform a numeric comparison:

```sql
Parameters [Enter Date] As DateTime;
Select * 
From YourTable
Where Abs(Fix([YourDateField])-Fix([Enter Date])) = 1
```